# Is there a way to check if .ahk script is running through Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autohotkey

I tried to create a Python script that goes through all my autohotkey scripts and runs them if they aren't running. This was simple enough for scripts converted into executables, but I haven't been able to find a way to see if .ahk scripts are running. I tried using python autohotkey libraries, but I haven't managed to find any with this functionality.

How would this be possible using Python?

Answer (score 2):

The processes are all going to be named AutoHotkey.exe, but they were all started with different arguments. The first (and by default the only) argument is going to be a path to the script that's running.

You can check this for example with the task manager, just enable the commandline column in the processes tab. Alternatively, you can use e.g. [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see it even easier.

And about getting the commandline in Python, I don't know Python, but you're likely going to want to use [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/using-wmi)/[(C)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic).
Easiest way is probably going to be using some Python WMI library. A Google search gives me [this one](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/), probably worth taking a look at.

Here's an example PowerShell command for using WMI to get the commandlines:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'AutoHotkey.exe'" | Format-List -Property CommandLine
```

Wouldn't be too hard to parse the desired info from that either, if doing it *properly* gets too complicated.